# Queue Question for an Algorithms Assignment

Tags: algorithm, queue, pseudocode

I'm trying to figure this out,

'Write the pseudo code for an algorithm isQSimilar(Q1,Q2) to check whether two queues, Q1 and Q2, are similar or not. (i.e. same elements in both queues and the same order of elements) At the end of the comparison, both queues should look unchanged. The only basic operations that you can use on the queues are the following: addQueue(), deleteQueue(), Qsize(), Rear() and Front().'

So what I have so far,

```
isQsimilar(Q1,Q2)

char check1;
char check2;

int n = Q1.Qsize();
int i = Q2.Qsize();

if (n != i)
    return false;
else
    while (n > 0)
    {
        check1 = Q1.front();
        check2 = Q2.front();

        if (check1 != check2)
            return false;

        Q1.deleteQueue(check1);
        Q2.deleteQueue(check2);

        check1 = Q1.rear();
        check2 = Q2.rear();

        Q1.addQueue(check2);
        Q2.addQueue(check2);

        n--;
    }

return true;
```

I'm not sure if I'm using the operations correctly or if what I'm doing is remotely correct. Am I in the right direction or am I missing something?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to check rear elements. I assume that `front()` only peeks front elements without removing while `deleteQueue()` removes front element from the queue

```
check1 = Q1.front();
check2 = Q2.front();
if (check1 != check2)
    return false;

Q1.deleteQueue();
Q2.deleteQueue();

Q1.addQueue(check1);
Q2.addQueue(check2);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly remove elements from Queues and append them later if they are same..

```
pseducode:
function isQueuesSame(Q, Q1){
    var size = Q.getSize();
    var size1 = Q1.getSize();

    if(size != size1) return false;
    else{
        while(size--){
            var peek = Q.deleteQueue();
            var peek1 = Q1.deleteQueue();

            if(peek != peek1) return false;

            Q.addQueue(peek);
            Q1.addQueue(peek1);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```